# How do I create a rest web service in Grails?

Tags: web-services, rest, grails

The idea is to call a method from a website(in php) to my application (in Grails). The application will serve data in json format.

The website and the application are hosted in two different servers. The website is on Yahoo and the application is on Rackspace.

Now, I want to create a web service in my Grails application which serves list of cities in json format.

**City Class**

```
   class City {
      String name
      String code
   }
```

How do i write the web service method?

Comment: Every thing you need to know about webservices in grails is in the documentation: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html

Answer (score 1):

Try the grails jaxrs plugin (https://github.com/krasserm/grails-jaxrs) which will do excactly what you want without any hassle.

Simply install it, create a `Resource` object with the introduced `create-resource` command and create and annotate the methods as you wish. all other things are managed by the plugin so you don't have to worry about `Controller` or `UrlMapping`...

Answer (score 1):

You need only the annotation @Resource(uri='/cities') on your domain and call the url/cities.json (but, its'n RESTful)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a few tools, first you will create a controller that deals with the requests and pushes them off to your service layer.

You can use URL Mappings to make it more RESTFul check out the [doc](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#REST) that way all the http methods will be mapped to actions in your controller.

Also if you will be doing a fair bit of json I would recomend starting with the [gson plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gson) it has a fuller feature set then the built in JSON support.

The link from the comment above is a great resource to read as well.

I have found that I most of the time want to support the accept header as well in which case you will need to update your config with the following code. See [withFormat doc](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) for more info.

```
grails.mime.use.accept.header = true
```